# querying mongodb whether there is data

Tags: python

My question is this.

I want to take action based on whether there is data on MongoDB or not.

If there is no data, I want it to enter that data with the input method, and if it has entered the data before, I want it to continue.

I wrote a code like this but it didn't work:

```
okulvarmi = { "okul" }

okul = db.find(okulvarmi)

if okul == "null":
  print("No data is included. Please add.")

else:
  print("The data has already been added. You can continue the transaction.")
```

The code above didn't work.

How can I do the system I say?

Comment: "null" should try to match the string null and not a null value. Check if this works for you, if value==None:

Comment: I did as you said. But `okulvarmi = {"okul"}` wants it to be JSON to query code. What data will I give?

Comment: Try using this format {"some field": "FIND ME!"}, the field you are trying to search has a field name, I'm guessing its "name". So do this, `okulvarmi = { "name": "okul" }` and then use the find function. And this might look like JSON but its just python dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

the 'okul' variable's value is 'null' so it is a string.

so it is better try as below:

```
if len(okul) == 0:
    print("No data is included. Please add.")
```

Comment: `okul = db.find( "okul" )`
He wants this code to be JSON.

But since I just wanted to question whether there is data or not, I did not know what data to give.

What should I do?

Comment: well it is not a JSON format. JSON is more key:value format such as "bina":"okul".
You should better to look at querying in mongodb I think the issue is about it. If else statement won't work due to "okul" string in first condition as well.

Comment: I do not understand what they are saying because I use translation. Can you get me running the code?

Comment: I don't know your mongodb structure, you should provide mongodb collection names and at least one working query. it is not proper question for SO, I guess nobody can get you the running code since the problem is not clear.